# useEffect not called in React Native when back to screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

How are you.
This is scenario of this issue.
Let's say there are 2 screens to make it simple.

1. enter A screen. useEffect of A screen called.
2. navigate to B screen from A screen
3. navigate back to A screen from B.
   at this time, useEffect is not called.

   ```
   function CompanyComponent(props) {

      const [roleID, setRoleID] = useState(props.user.SELECTED_ROLE.id)

      useEffect(()=>{ 

    // this called only once when A screen(this component) loaded,  
    // but when comeback to this screen, it doesn't called
      setRoleID(props.user.SELECTED_ROLE.id)
    }, [props.user])
   }
   ```

So the updated state of Screen A remain same when comeback to A screen again (Not loading from props)

I am not changing props.user in screen B.
But I think    `const [roleID, setRoleID] = useState(props.user.SELECTED_ROLE.id)` this line should be called at least.

I am using redux-persist. I think this is not a problem.
For navigation, I use this

```
// to go first screen A, screen B
function navigate(routeName, params) {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    );
}
// when come back to screen A from B
function goBack() {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.back()
    );
}
```

Is there any callback I can use when the screen appears?
What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Do you change props.user when you go back to screen A?

Comment: The `useEffect` isn't called again because `props.user` remains the same in your case...you can use multiple `useEffects` in one component :)

Comment: How are you navigating between screen? Can you add some code?

Comment: What navigation package are you using? Does the navigation do more of a stack and not unmount "back" "pages"? The `useEffect` hook will only fire on first render and whenever a value in its dependency array update, so I suspect it isn't getting triggered again by not being remounted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

React Navigation 5 provide a useFocusEffect hook, is analogous to useEffect, the only difference is that it only runs if the screen is currently focused. Check the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect

```html
 useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = setRoleID(props.user.SELECTED_ROLE.id)
      return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [props.user])
  )
```

Comment: sigh...Every time I dismiss my dialog box on my screen, the app treats the behavior as focusing the screen underneath the dialog box. So the `setShowDialog(true)` within my `useFocusEffect()` keeps triggering each time I dismiss the dialog box

Comment: You can't put the `useCallback` hook in the `useFocusEffect` one.

Comment: Hi @AdrianBartholomew! Why? It's how it's implemented in the React Navigation documentation.

Comment: That surprises me.  Link?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Answer (score 150):

Below solution worked for me:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

const ExampleScreen = (props) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("called");
 
        // Call only when screen open or when back on screen 
        if(isFocused){ 
            getInitialData();
        }
    }, [props, isFocused]);

    const getInitialData = async () => {}    

    return (
        ......
        ......
    )
}
```

I've used react navigation 5+

> @react-navigation/native": "5.6.1"

Comment: I've used ```useEffect(() => {
if(isFocused){        
console.log("called");
        getInitialData();
}
    }, [ isFocused]);```

Seemed to work better

Comment: Perfect, very smart solution

Comment: Why not [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect) ?

Comment: @SamuelDeBacker useFocusEffect: Use to trigger any function or method with screen gets focused or unfocused. useIsFocused: Use to refresh UI components from the return method when the screen gets focused or unfocused. so, second one is more generic.

Comment: Could someone pls explain me why [props, isfocused]  instead of [isfocused] ?

Comment: @oguz I think the author of the answer just adopted the code to the OP. I am using `[currentDate, isFocused]` to fetch data when a) the date has changed and b) the user navigates back from a view to create data.

Answer (score 21):

When you navigate from A to B, component A is not destroyed (it stays in the navigation stack). Therefore, when you navigate back the code does not run again.

Perhaps a better way to acheive what you want to to use the navigation lifecycle events (I am assuming you are using `react-navigation`) I.e. subscribe to the `didFocus` event and run whatever code you want whenever the component is focussed E.g

```
const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
    console.log('focussed');
});
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe when appropriate e.g.

```
// sometime later perhaps when the component is unmounted call the function returned from addListener. In this case it was called unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: May I know how to unscribe?

Comment: To unsubscribe, you just need to call the function that was returned from `addListener`. In the above example I called it `unsubscribe`. I have updated the answer above too. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If you are using react-navigation 5.x give a try to [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect#how-is-usefocuseffect-different-from-adding-a-listener-for-focus-event)

Comment: true for react-navigation 4.4

Answer (score 10):

The current version of React Navigation provides the useFocusEffect hook. See [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect).

Answer (score 7):

The above mentioned solution would work definitely but in any case you need to know why it happens here is the reason,

In react native all the screens are stacked meaning they follow the **LAST-IN-FIRST-OUT** order, so when you are on a SCREEN A and go.Back(), the component(Screen A) would get un-mounted because it was the last screen that was added in the stack but when we naviagte to SCREEN B, it won't get un-mounted and the next SCREEN B would be added in the stack.

So now, when you go.Back() to SCREEN A, the useEffect will not run because it never got un-mounted.
React-native keeps the navigation this way to make it look more **responsive and real time**.

if you want to un-mount the Screen everytime you navigate to some other screen you might want to try **navigation.replace** than navigation.navigate

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native"; 
 
const focus = useIsFocused();  // useIsFocused as shown          
 
useEffect(() => {   // whenever you are in the current screen, it will be true vice versa
    if(focus == true){ // if condition required here because it will call the function even when you are not focused in the screen as well, because we passed it as a dependencies to useEffect hook
       handleGetProfile();
    }
}, [focus]);
```

[more](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/)

Answer (score 4):

Solution with `useEffect`

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Component = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const isFocused = useMemo(() => navigation.isFocused(), [])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      // place your logic
    }
  }, [isFocused])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue but because the data I was updating on screen B and displaying on screen A was also being used on other screens it made perfect sense to put **this set of data** in a `redux store slice`.

Besides in my case screen A was placed in a tab navigator and had a few sibling screens in other tabs the user could swipe left/right to. This made `useFocusEffect` problematic since it was firing on each swipe and for other reasons I wanted to avoid that.

Anyway, with redux I could get away with `useEffect` not firing on going back. Just a hint alongside other solutions suggested here.