# useEffect is not called when navigating back to screen - React Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a screen that makes a call to an api to fetch some data which is then displayed

An issue that I am seeing is that when I navigate away from the screen (I am using react-navigation 6.x) and then go back to it `useEffect()` is not being called

From what I have read so far, this is down to the value of `userId` not changing (I think i need to do some more reading around the `useEffect()` hook to understand better, maybe someone will help clear things up with this question)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import AppContext from '../../components/AppContext.js';

export const CreateNewEvent = () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(AppContext);
  const userId = globalContext.userInfo.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({userId});
    fetch(eventTypesUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json'},
      body: body,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setEventTypeData(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, [userId]);

}
```

So in my scenario I am on Screen 1 (Here i can create an event which makes a request to get all event types and loads them into a select menu)

When I navigate to Screen 2 (to create an event type) and then back to Screen 1, the `useEffect()` hook is not called resulting in being unable to see the event type I have just created (hope that makes sense)..  also notice that any data entered in Screen 1 previously still remains

I have come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182942/useeffect-not-called-in-react-native-when-back-to-screen) which appears to be what I am dealing with, just a little unsure how to implement with my setup

How can I ensure that Screen 2 makes the api call when i go back and that all previous form data is cleared out?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the core, React Navigation does not rerender the screen when a user navigates back to that screen for performance optimization and avoids unnecessary rerenders.

When required, They provide a useful hook to detect when screen is focused and run some side effects.

Let refactor code as below:

```js
Top-level import 
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/core";

// Run side effects when screen focused, navigated, or visited 

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({ userId });
    fetch(eventTypesUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      body: body,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setEventTypeData(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));

    return () => {
      // Run  somelogisx when user leave screen,
      // Cleaning caches or cancelling subscriptions
    };
  }, [userId]),
);
```

**Note:** `React.useCallback` is part of `useFocusEffect` API. The React Navigation team trying to optimize screen performance with memoization.

Comment: Thank you providing your answer. Looking at the 2 answers here, what’s the difference between useIsFocused and useFocusEffect?

Comment: `useIsFocused` is mostly used when you need to conditionally render UI depending on if screen focused. `useFocusEffect` design for handling side effects. `useIsFocused` combined with `useEffect` can achieve the same result as `useFocusEffect`.

Comment: didn't work in my case !! :-(

Comment: Same, it spammed my bundler, and would not let me click andy buttons.

Answer (score 7):

In React Native, when you are navigating forward then every screen is just pushed to navigation stack.

Now, when you navigate back the previous screen is popped out and the topmost screen in the stack is displayed. Since nothing(state or props) has changed in the topmost screen, it will not be re-rendered.

So you have to do some manual work.

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";


const isFocused = useIsFocused();
```

isFocused is boolean

```
useEffect(() => {

 if (userId && isFocused) {
   // Code which you want to execute when screen is loaded first 
   // time(and after userId is initialised) or loaded after press of 
   // back button     
 }
 
    
}, [userId, isFocused]);
```

Comment: So i pass isFocused and userId into the useEffect array?

Comment: Yes, let me update the answer

Comment: this is the best answer adding, adding isFocused as a dependency trigger makes react to rerun the Effect everytime the value of isFocused changes