# useEffect not working in Stack Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 screens in Stack Navigator.

**All Categories,**
**Add a new category**

In the **All Categories** screen, all categories are displayed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadCategories();
  }, []);
```

This is the `useEffect` hook that load all the categories.

I have made a touchable opacity to navigate to **Add a new category** screen, So users can easily add a new category if needed.

**What I'm expecting to do:** So after adding a new category and going back to the **All Categories** screen `loadCategories()` should run again, So the user can see the newly added category there. But the problem is when I add a new category and go back the `loadCategories()` function doesn't execute again. What will be the cause for this?

Comment: add category function is it post request ?

Comment: It is a get request

Comment: try get('domain/addCategory').then( (res)=> {loadCategories()})

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182942/useeffect-not-called-in-react-native-when-back-to-screen?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer which is relatable to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703838/19317939

```
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';

...
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) loadCategories();
  }, [isFocused]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load categories when screen is focus

```
function Categories({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadCategories = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     loadCategories();
    });

    return loadCategories;
  }, [navigation]);

  ...rest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Often we need to fetch data when we come to some screens back,

For this, **there is a hook from the @react-navigation/native library  (useFocusEffect)**, which we can use to accomplish such requirements.

For Ex.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(user));

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```

In the above code, Whenever the ProfileContent screen is getting focused, the code inside the useFocusEffect will re-run.

[Refer to official docs for in-depth understanding.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)