# UseEffect is not getting called when I navigate in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

`useEffect` is not getting called when I navigate to this page in react native.

The problem is as follows:
I have .js file that handles my functions and data to give it to .jsx that builds my UI. When I navigate I enter the js file and then build the UI.

This is the code I'm having issues with:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import PublicacionPropiedadUI from './publicacionPropiedadUI';
import { getAssetById } from '../../../api/assetsAPI';

export default function PublicacionPropiedad({ route }) { //tendria que recibir id para hacer una busqueda en bd
    const { propiedadId } = route.params;

    const [propiedad, setPropiedad] = useState([])
    //const [botones, setBotones] = useState(false)
    console.log(propiedadId,'45');
    useEffect(() => {
        let respuesta
        const busquedaPropiedades = async () => {

            try {
                console.log(propiedadId,'4');
                respuesta = await getAssetById(propiedadId)
                console.log(respuesta);
                setPropiedad(respuesta.asset[0]);

   
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al obtener la busqduedass:', error);
            }




        };

        busquedaPropiedades()
 

        /* setPropiedad(detallePropiedad)
        analisisBtnera() */

    }, [])



    //console.log(propiedad, 'trass');
    return (

        <PublicacionPropiedadUI propiedad={propiedad} />


    )
}
```

That code is the exact same one that I have in another page, and it works perfectly.

I tried `console.log` everywhere and determined that it didn't enter `useEffect`. The `useEffect` is used to call for an API that works too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect not called in React Native when back to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182942/useeffect-not-called-in-react-native-when-back-to-screen)

Comment: @August check a new solution

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior by React Navigation to avoid unnecessary screen re-renders every time user visited screen which has previously visited.

Use [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)  hook to  for  handling side effects or simply use [useIsFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused) value as a dependence for standard useEffect:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import PublicacionPropiedadUI from "./publicacionPropiedadUI";
import { getAssetById } from "../../../api/assetsAPI";

export default function PublicacionPropiedad({ route }) {
  //tendria que recibir id para hacer una busqueda en bd
  const { propiedadId } = route.params;
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const [propiedad, setPropiedad] = useState([]);
  //const [botones, setBotones] = useState(false)
  console.log(propiedadId, "45");
  useEffect(() => {
    let respuesta;
    const busquedaPropiedades = async () => {
      try {
        console.log(propiedadId, "4");
        respuesta = await getAssetById(propiedadId);
        console.log(respuesta);
        setPropiedad(respuesta.asset[0]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener la busqduedass:", error);
      }
    };

    busquedaPropiedades();

    /* setPropiedad(detallePropiedad)
        analisisBtnera() */
  }, [isFocused]);

  //console.log(propiedad, 'trass');
  return <PublicacionPropiedadUI propiedad={propiedad} />;
}
```